# how to resolve ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x' using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot pie chart using variable data. Below is my code.

```
tot = ['Государство, общество, политика','Социальная сфера',
       'Оборона,безопасность,законность','Экономика',
       'Жилищно-коммунальная сфера']
#labels = list(tot)
 
data = data[['Распределение вопросов, содержащихся в обращениях, по тематическим разделам / государство, общество, политик',
'Распределение вопросов, содержащихся в обращениях, по тематическим разделам / социальная сфер',
'Распределение вопросов, содержащихся в обращениях, по тематическим разделам / оборона, безопасность, законност',
'Распределение вопросов, содержащихся в обращениях, по тематическим разделам / экономик',
'Распределение вопросов, содержащихся в обращениях, по тематическим разделам / жилищно-коммунальная сфе']]
  
# Creating plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))
plt.pie(data, labels=tot, autopct='%1.0f%%')
 
# show plot
plt.show()
```

this is the error that is being generated.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-659ba211c19c> in <module>()
     12 # Creating plot
     13 fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))
---> 14 plt.pie(data, labels=tot, autopct='%1.0f%%')
     15 
     16 # show plot

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in pie(self, x, explode, labels, colors, autopct, pctdistance, shadow, labeldistance, startangle, radius, counterclock, wedgeprops, textprops, center, frame, rotatelabels)
   2927             explode = [0] * len(x)
   2928         if len(x) != len(labels):
-> 2929             raise ValueError("'label' must be of length 'x'")
   2930         if len(x) != len(explode):
   2931             raise ValueError("'explode' must be of length 'x'")

ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'
```

Please help me, how to overcome this issue.

Comment: This piece of code looks incorrect. `data = data[['...']]`. What is inside your `data` variable?

It is complaining that the variable `label` (your `tot`) has not the same length as your variable `data`.

Comment: @physicalattraction in these columns is the number of entries. just numbers. dtype is int. all columns are the same size, no nan

Comment: Well, if you print the variables `data` and `tot` one line above your invocation to `pie()`, you will find they do not have the same length.

Comment: @physicalattraction I realized my mistake. thx a lot!